# With Elasticsearch function score query with decay against a geo-point, is it possible to set a target distance?

Tags: elasticsearch

It doesn't seem possible based on https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html , but I'd like confirmation.

In plain English, I'm asking to score the results (with geo-point locations) by how close they are to 500km from some latitude, longitude origin.

It's confusing because there is a parameter called "offset" but according to the documentation it doesn't seem to be an offset from origin (eg. distance) but instead seems to mean "threshold" instead.

Comment: If I get you right, you basically want the decay function to work as if the origin was on a ring at 500km distance from the origin point? Sort of like a wave/donut like this: http://i1-win.softpedia-static.com/screenshots/Gauss_5.jpg

Comment: Yes, I think so, Val! Is that possible with the built-in decay parameters or should I just resort to a custom script?

Comment: Great answer to understand decay function parameters https://stackoverflow.com/a/47844222/1282910

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a few ways to accomplish this:

A. One way would be to simply sort by distance in reverse order from the origin. You'd use a [`geo_distance` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-distance-query.html) and then [sort by distance](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#geo-sorting). In the following query, the most distant documents will come up first, i.e. the sort value is the distance from the origin and we're sorting in decreasing order.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "geo_distance": {
          "from" : "100km",
          "to" : "200km",
          "location": {
            "lat": 10,
            "lon": 20
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_geo_distance": {
        "location": {
          "lat": 10,
          "lon": 20
        },
        "order": "desc",
        "unit": "km",
        "distance_type": "plane"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

B. The second way involves using a [`geo_distance_range` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-distance-range-query.html) in order to define a "ring" around the origin. The width of that ring could somehow symbolize the offset + scale you'd use in a gauss function (although there would be no decay). Here we define a ring that is 10km wide at 500km distance from the origin point and sort the documents by distance in that ring.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "geo_distance_range": {
          "from": "495km",
          "to": "505km",
          "location": {
            "lat": 10,
            "lon": 20
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_geo_distance": {
        "location": {
          "lat": 10,
          "lon": 20
        },
        "order": "desc",
        "unit": "km",
        "distance_type": "plane"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

C. The last way is a bit more involved. We're basically after an "inverse gauss" shape, basically [this figure (33)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/decay-functions.html), but upside-down, or [this one](https://1millionmonkeystyping.files.wordpress.com/2014/07/euclid24.jpg) which better represents the donut shape we're after. We can combine solution B above with a `gauss` function that would only score within that ring. In the query below, we're basically saying that we're only interested in the locations around 500km from the origin and we let a gauss function kick in only for those documents. It's not perfect, though, but might be close enough to what you need.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "geo_distance_range": {
          "from": "495km",
          "to": "505km",
          "location": {
            "lat": 10,
            "lon": 20
          }
        }
      },
      "query": {
        "function_score": {
          "functions": [
            {
              "gauss": {
                "location": {
                  "origin": {
                    "lat": 10,
                    "lon": 20
                  },
                  "offset": "500km",
                  "scale": "5km"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "_score": "desc"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Val! To clarify C), will the gauss function kick in on the range 495 - 505?

Comment: Yes, only in that range since you won't get any documents before 495km and after 505km. You might need to tune the offset/scale settings, though.