# Elasticsearch scoring documents liked by similar users higher

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

In Elasticsearch I have two indexes, `places` and `users`. This is the mapping for places:

```
mappings: {
  location: {
    type: "geo_point"
  }
}
```

And this is the mapping for users:

```
mappings: {
  likes: {
    type: "keyword"
  },
  seen: {
    type: "keyword"
  }
}
```

As you can see a user can like and see different places. Now I want to query places which a user has not seen or liked yet and want to show places which are liked by users who like similar places as the querying user first. This is the query I was able to come up with:

```
POST /places/_search
{
  "_source": [
    "id"
  ],
  "size": 1,
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "_id": {
                  "index": "users",
                  "id": "vu0E1rjJEqcgyfj29fwZ",
                  "path": "seen"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "terms": {
                "_id": {
                  "index": "users",
                  "id": "vu0E1rjJEqcgyfj29fwZ",
                  "path": "likes"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "filter": {
            "geo_distance": {
              "distance": "200km",
              "location": {
                "lat": 52,
                "lon": 13
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "random_score": {},
      "boost_mode": "replace"
    }
  }
}
```

However, at this moment this query just assigns a random score to all results. As I'm new to Elasticsearch I'm struggling to come up with a scoring function to achieve scoring places, that similar users have liked, higher, especially because the data about user likes is stored in a different index than the one I'm actually querying. What would be the best approach this problem? Is something like this even possible with my current data model?

Answer (score 0):

**I think you have to perform two request like below**

1. Get all the similar user's likes location ids
2. Then use the location ids to match and exclude the likes and seen location

Step 1 query example :

```
GET users/_search
{
  "_source": [
    "likes"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "likes": {
              "index": "users",
              "id": "vu0E1rjJEqcgyfj29fwZ",
              "path": "likes"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "ids": {
            "values": [
              vu0E1rjJEqcgyfj29fwZ
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Step 2 query example :

```
GET places/_search
{
  "_source": [
    "id"
  ],
  "size": 1,
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "ids": {
                "values": [] # Put all the similar user like ids here
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "_id": {
                  "index": "users",
                  "id": "vu0E1rjJEqcgyfj29fwZ",
                  "path": "seen"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "terms": {
                "_id": {
                  "index": "users",
                  "id": "vu0E1rjJEqcgyfj29fwZ",
                  "path": "likes"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "filter": {
            "geo_distance": {
              "distance": "200km",
              "location": {
                "lat": 52,
                "lon": 13
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "random_score": {},
      "boost_mode": "replace"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a gauss decay function from within your function score query, as nicely described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35193017/8160318):

```
GET /places/_search
{
  "size": 5,
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "_id": {
                  "index": "users",
                  "type": "_doc",
                  "id": "vu0E1rjJEqcgyfj29fwZ",
                  "path": "seen"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "terms": {
                "_id": {
                  "index": "users",
                  "type": "_doc",
                  "id": "vu0E1rjJEqcgyfj29fwZ",
                  "path": "likes"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "gauss": {
            "location": {
              "origin": {
                "lat": 52,
                "lon": 13
              },
              "scale": "200km"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "boost_mode": "replace"
    }
  }
}
```

But I wonder what the current connection between the `likes` and `places` is in your data model.

Comment: I'm sorry but this answer misses the point of my question, as your answer is focused on distance-based scoring while I want to achieve scoring based on users interests/likes